# mvc3 PRG pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, redirect, post-redirect-get

Is it bad practice when using the PRG pattern to show the currentId for the typed model in the URL (data posted to item with id=586 to controller -> controller handles data then redirects to get -> get collects data with id=586 and sends it to a view -> view displays data with id=586)?

```
http://XXXXX/ViewPage?currentId=586
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a good idea, and will be confusing if you automatically get the id from some other property. The user will expect in the future that if they reload the final redirect url, they would see the same thing they see now. You would need the id to do that.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback.  I have been unsure lately if having the id was considered bad practice and explored options for removing it from the passed parameters with TempData or Session.  From the responses here (from you and others) it seems that leaving it in is not harmful (so long as malicious attempts to change it are handled - try catch and authorization, etc..).  On a side note: Using TempData (which is stored in session) or Session would provide the user with the ability to refresh.